# Complex polynomial function problem and inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider a polynomial function: 
$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2 z^2+...+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z^n,$$ 
where $n\le1$, $a_0\neq0$, $z$ and $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}$ are complex numbers. Let 
$$A=\max(|a_0|,|a_1|,...,|a_{n-1}|)>0.$$

Show that 
$$|a_0+a_1+a_2 z^2+...+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|\le nA|z|^{n-1}$$
 when $|z| \ge 1$, and conclude that if $|z|\ge nA+1 := P_0$ then $|f(z)|\ge |z|^n-nA|z|^{n-1}>0 $

I tried to have
\begin{align*}
|a_0+a_1z+a_2 z^2+...+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}|&\le |a_0|+|a_1z|+|a_2z^2|+...+|a_{n-1} z^{n-1}| \\
&=|a_0|+|a_1||z|+|a_2||z|^2+...+|a_{n-1}| |z|^{n-1}
\end{align*}
and try to use the natural Euclidean length and the fact that $|zw|=|z||w|$ if $z$, $w$ are complex, but nothing happens.

Comment: When $|z| \geq 1$, $|z|^n \geq |z|^k$ for $n \geq k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done:
\begin{align*}
|a_0+a_1z+a_2 z^2+...+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}| &\le |a_0|+|a_1z|+|a_2z^2|+...+|a_{n-1} z^{n-1}| \\
&= |a_0|+|a_1||z|+|a_2||z|^2+...+|a_{n-1}| |z|^{n-1} \\
&\le A+A|z|+A|z|^2+...+A |z|^{n-1} \\
&\le An|z|^{n-1} \\
\end{align*}
since $|z| \ge 1$ (so $|z|^k \le |z|^{n-1}$ for $k \le n-1$).